# How do I make xgettext support i18n Java?

Tags: java, internationalization, gettext

I am trying to extract the strings from a Java project using xgettext with the following line:

```
xgettext --lanaguage=Java C:\workspace\HelloWorldJava\src\com\Dummy.java
```

and I get the following error:

```
language 'Java' unknown
```

When I remove the --lanaguage=Java parameter and execute the same line I get the following:

```
warning:file 'C:\workspace\HelloWorldJava\src\com\Dummy.java' extension 'java' is unknown; will try C
```

How do I make xgettext support i18n Java?

I am running xgettext win 32 binary ("GNU gettext for WIN32") on Windows 7 64-bit from here:

http://franco-bez.4lima.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=55&Itemid=64&lang=en

Comment: Really `--lanaguage=...`? Twice used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have installed a quite old version of Gettext. By inspecting the source code of the package available on the URL you provided, Java support is not available. You should download and install a newer Gettext port for Windows.

Django's documentation includes some [easy-to-follow instructions to install Gettext on Windows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/localization/#gettext-on-windows).